# FATAL_ERROR: Iteration limit 10000 is reached

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fatal-error, xilinx, vivado

It is over 2 weeks I faced a probem, Im programming an artix 7 FPGA. The process is simple:

- a serial module receive 2 bitstreams(2 bytes)
- Demux module according to these 2 bytes enable 2 bits in array puf_en

when I add demux module to the whoe design, during the simulation I receive this Error:
FATAL_ERROR: Iteration limit 10000 is reached.

The code for demux is here:

```
    PUF_STATE_PROCESS:process(clk,uart_read,PUF_signal,UART_READ_FLAG)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (uart_read="11111111") then-- this means reset
                                stop_s<='0';

                                puf_signal<=initial;
                                reset_s<='1';
                                LED_S<="1111";

        else

            case puf_signal is
                    When initial=>
                              reset_s<='1';
                              puf_en_s<=(others=>'0');
                              LED_S<="0001";
                              --if   UART_READ_FLAG='1' then
                                if uart_read/="11111110" then

                                else
                                         stop_s<='0';

                                         puf_signal<=ch_i;                                   
                                end if;   
                            --   end if;      
                    When ch_i =>
                                if UART_READ="11111110" or UART_READ="11111111"  then

                                else
                                        ch_i_s<=(uart_read);

                                        puf_signal<=ch_j;
                                        LED_S<="0010";
                                end if;
                    when ch_j=>
                               if UART_READ="11111110" or UART_READ="11111111" or uart_read=ch_i_s  then

                               else
                               ch_j_s<=(uart_read);
                              mux_en_s_j<=uart_read;
                               puf_signal<=start;
                               timer_s<=(others=>'0');
                               LED_S<="0011";
                                end if;
                    when start=>
                                reset_s<='0';

                                if timer_start<10000 then
                                        mux_en_s_i<=ch_i_s;
                                        mux_en_s_j<=ch_j_s;
                                       timer_start<=timer_start+1;

                                        for i in 0 to (RO_Number) loop
                                            if i=ch_i_s then
                                                puf_en_s(i)<='1';                    
                                            elsif i=ch_j_s then

                                              puf_en_s(i)<='1';
                                            else
                                                puf_en_s(i)<='0';

                                             end if;
                                          end loop;            


                                       LED_S<="0100";
                                else

                                        puf_signal<=finish;
                                        timer_start<=0;
                                        LED_S<="0101";
                              end if;

                      when finish=>
                      if timer_s<timer_max_value then
                              timer_s<=timer_s+'1';

                              puf_en_s<=(others=>'0');
                              LED_S<="0100";
                      else
                             stop_s<='1'; 
                             timer_s<=(others=>'0');
                             LED_S<="0111";
                             puf_signal<=initial; 
                      end if;


            end case;
         end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Can anyone tel me what is wrong with my code? i tested severa different approaches but I have this error.

Thanks

Comment: What is `R0_Number`?

Comment: it is a constant value equa to 63

Comment: I have also warning about loops for serial module but when I deactivate demux modue it works

Comment: There is immediately nothing that looks alarmingly wrong. Only that you don't need other than clk in the sensitivity list. If you would provide a minimal entity/architecture pair and a testbench that exhibits the problem someone might take a look. It might be that this is even not the source of your problem (e.g. you by any change didn't forget 'not' from clock generation in clk <= not clk after period/2, wouldn't be the first one to do so...)

Comment: As you said, I removed other signas from sensivity ist but nothing changed, I also removed serial modue, but still the problem is valid

Comment: Without the ports for demux (all the declarations), knowing where it's outputs are used and how, it doesn't appear the problem is in this process. There's only one loop statement and it's has a for iteration scheme. There are no assignments that are not on a clock edge (no combinatorial loops). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This may occur due to zero delay assignments in your Ring Oscillator (combinatorial feedback). Without delay you'd run into the delta cycle limit. Where is puf_en_s used?

Comment: You are right, The problem in simulation was for combinational loop in Ring oscilator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was not in this code.It was actually correlated to the Ring oscillators.In Ring Oscillators there was combinational loops with zero delay and it caused this problem